How to revoke warehouse priviledge for role in Snowflake
I am trying to run query while selecting role AP_KPO_ANL with warehouse OP_WH. But now i created another new warehouse and grant role access to this new warehouse.
Now i want to revoke access for warehouse OP_WH from role AP_KPO_ANL. I tried below revoke queries but still when i select role AP_KPO_ANL i can access warehouse OP_WH and run query.
    REVOKE GRANT OPTION FOR OPERATE ON WAREHOUSE OP_WH FROM ROLE AP_KPO_ANL;
    REVOKE OPERATE ON WAREHOUSE OP_WH FROM ROLE AP_KPO_ANL;
    REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON WAREHOUSE OP_WH FROM ROLE AP_KPO_ANL;


Is there a secondary role granted to your user that has privileges on that warehouse? What do you see when you run show grants to user/role?

thanks there are two roles assigned to user and i just ran the same queries as mentioned in question for second role also but still the same error

Which role is the owner of OP_WH? Is that owner role "under" AP_KPO_NL role in the role hierarchy?

Probably not required but log out/in to make sure any changes have taken effect. Then either start with the warehouse or with the user and work your way up/down the privilege/grant hierarchy until you find the link between the user and the warehouse

can you maybe provide command to check owner of OP_WH or through grant hierarchy ? I tried to logout and login again but same issue

when i run Show WAREHOUSES; i found out SYSADMIN is the owner of warehouse OP_WH

Hey @Andrew
In such cases, you can utilize the query results to view the output. By this I mean, run the below queries together, so this will retrieve the results from first query and transfer the results to the second query.
show grants on warehouse OP_WH;
SELECT * FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID())) where "privilege" = 'OWNERSHIP';
Since you have already found out the owner of the warehouse, try submitting the revoke using SYSADMIN role.

yes i already tried submiting the revoke using SYSADMIN but still the same issue.

When you run "show grants on warehouse OP_WH" you can see the users/roles that have privileges on that warehouse. If one of those roles is AP_KPO_ANL then revoke the relevant warehouse privilege from that role. Otherwise work your way up through the role hierarchy until you get to AP_KPO_ANL and revoke the preceding role from AP_KPO_ANL

Please note, every grant is authorized by a particular grantor, which means that there can be multiple grants of the same permission to the same role, each with a different grantor.
To revoke the privilege, make sure the revoke command is executed by either the grantor of the privilege grant or by a role that inherits the grantor role as part of its role hierarchy.
Try revoking privileges on this warehouse that are granted to another role; and then also change the OWNERSHIP of the table, which was also owned by the other role.
There is a supporting KB article for your reference: https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Revoke-command-execution-succeeds-but-the-privilege-is-still-granted-to-the-role?
Option 2)
Try revoking some privileges on this warehouse in case granted to another role; and then also change the OWNERSHIP of the warehouse if owned by any other role.
